# How to continue with this Python homework?

Tags: python

> Write a program that uses a while loop. Process input that uses a sentinel value to indicate the end of input
>
> Write a program that reads a series of numbers from standard input and prints out the sum of those values.  A sentinel value of -999 will indicate the end of the input values.  Do not include the sentinel value in the sum.
>
> For example:
>
> [image: Example Snapshot]

Can anyone help me with this? This is what I have tried

```
user_input = 1
    while user_input = -999:
        user_input = int(input())
```

Comment: have you tried running your code in the python interpreter and playing with it? you would be better served by working through your assignments than posting them here without due diligence

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) The summary is that we are looking for focussed questions that will be useful for other readers. Thus, if you can edit it to indicate what _specific_ problem you are facing, that would be ideal.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this, This code portion will break when it reaches the value till it matches the sentinel.

```
value = 0
while True:
    old_value, value = value, way_to_new_value
    if value == old_value: break
```